# Changing a field in the users table after_create of a record satisfies a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I want to change a users workout_id in the Users table once he completes his workout. I can't figure out how to do this. Below are the two ways I've tried to figure this out.

**Attempt 1:** Put an if statement in the controller, that when true increments the users workout_id - The problem is the if statement only passes when the condition is already true, so the user needs to try to complete an additional exercise after his workout is already complete.

Example:

```
def create
    @completed_set = CompletedSet.new(params[:completed_set])

    if @totalExercisesInWorkout.included_in?(@completedExercises) == true
      raise "it worked!"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @completed_set.save
        format.html { redirect_to profile_path, notice: 'Successfully completed set.' }
        format.json { render json: @completed_set, status: :created, location: @completed_set }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @completed_set.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Attempt 2** use the `after_save` callback in the Model. - this doesn't work because I don't have access to the session information in the Model, so I can't know what the user is, what their workout_id is, and if they have finished their workout.

There must be a simple solution to this problem, but I'm totally stumped!

Thanks!

EDIT:

A workout is complete when an array with the exercise_id's of the workout is matched by an array of the completed_set exercise_is's of the user. So when the following code is true:

```
@totalExercisesInWorkout.included_in?(@completedExercises)
```

.include_in? is an extension of the Array Class that simply returns true if the second array includes all the values in the first array.

A workout `has_many` exercises 
When a user "completes" an exercise, that exercise and relevant information, such as user_id, workout_id, etc. is stored in the completed_set table.

In my `application_controller` I have an `initialize_vars` method that finds all the information I need to know about the user and their workouts. Here it is:

```
def initialize_vars
    @workout = Workout.find(current_user.workout_id)
    @user_program = current_user.program
    @user_cycle = Cycle.find(current_user.cycle_id)
    @user_group = Group.find(current_user.group_id)

    @exercise = @workout.exercises
    @workout_exercise = @workout.workout_exercises

    # Array needs to have an exercise for every set in the exercise
    @exercisesInWorkout = @workout.exercises.pluck(:exercise_id)
    # Array of the sets in the users current workout
    @workoutSets = @workout_exercise.pluck(:sets)
    # Array of exercises user has completed in current workout
    @completedExercises = CompletedSet.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:exercise_id) 
    # Array of exercise_id's in workout times the number of sets for each exercise
    @totalExercisesInWorkout = @exercisesInWorkout.zip(@workoutSets).map { |n1, n2| [n1] * n2 }.flatten

    #Total number of reps a user has completed
    @repsCompleted = CompletedSet.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:repetitions).sum

    #Total amount of weight a user has lifted
    @weightLifted = CompletedSet.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:weight).sum
  end
```

EDIT 2:

I've learned a lot here. I refactored my code. Here is what it looks like now.

```
Class User

def cycle
    Cycle.find(cycle_id)
  end

  def group
    Group.find(group_id)
  end

  def workout
    Workout.find(workout_id)
  end

  def completed_exercise_ids_array(user)
    CompletedSet.where(workout_id: workout_id, user_id: user).pluck(:exercise_id)
  end

  def sets_in_workout_array
    workout.workout_exercises.pluck(:sets)
  end

  def exercises_in_workout_times_sets_array
    workout.workout_exercises.pluck(:exercise_id).zip(sets_in_workout_array).map { |n1, n2| [n1] * n2 }.flatten
  end

  def update_workout_if_needed!
    if exercises_in_workout_times_sets_array.included_in?(completed_exercise_ids_array)
      self.workout.id = self.workout.next_workout_id
      save!
    end
  end

# Methods for progress area
  def total_reps_completed(user)
    CompletedSet.where(user_id: user).sum(:repetitions)
  end

  def total_weight_lifted(user)
    CompletedSet.where(user_id: user).sum(:weight)
  end
```

And my application_controller

```
class ApplicationController 

# Application wide instance variables go here. Just don't forget to call initialize_vars in the controllers you want to call these variables in.
  def initialize_vars
    @user_workout = current_user.workout
    @user_cycle = current_user.cycle
    @user_group = current_user.group

    @exercise = @user_workout.exercises

    # Array of the sets in the users current workout
    @workoutSets = current_user.sets_in_workout_array

    # Array of exercises user has completed in current workout
    @completedExercises = current_user.completed_exercise_ids_array(current_user) 

    # Array of exercise_id's in workout times the number of sets for each exercise
    @totalExercisesInWorkout = current_user.exercises_in_workout_times_sets_array

  end
```

I moved some logic to the profile_controller

Comment: The second approach seems correct, but I need to know more about your model structure and associations.  Can you post more info about these - and also what makes a workout 'complete'?

Comment: Just updated the question. Let me know if you need anything more specific.

Comment: I'm confused by the instance variables `@totalExercisesInWorkout` and `@completedExercises` in the controller. Why do these have to be instantiated in `ApplicationController`?

Comment: I don't know where else to instantiate them. I though that would be the cleanest place to put them since I may access them in other controllers. Is there a better way to get that information?

Comment: It's just that all those instance variables being assigned with every single action in every single controller is a bit much. Let alone all those database queries that will execute for every action in your controllers.

Comment: You're right. I refactored The code. I moved everything into methods in the User model, and instantiated only what I need across the app in the Application_Controller, and moved the re-written instance variables I need in the profile into the profile controller. I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: Does my refactored code make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `after_create` callback for CompletedSet would be the best place for this:

```
class CompletedSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :exercise

  after_create :update_user_workout

  def update_user_workout
    user.update_workout_if_needed!
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :completed_sets
  belongs_to :workout

  def completed_exercise_ids
    completed_sets.where(workout_id: workout_id).pluck(:exercise_id)
  end

  def update_workout_if_needed!
    if completed_exercise_ids.included_in?(workout.workout_exercises.pluck(:exercise_id))
      self.workout = Workout.next(workout)
      save!
    end
  end
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :exercises, through: :workout_exercises

  # some logic to determine the next workout - modify as needed
  def self.next(workout)
    where("workouts.sequence > ?", workout.sequence).order(:sequence).first
  end
end
```

This solution assumes that you have associated the `current_user` with the CompletedSet in your controller `create` action (which I'm not seeing):

```
def create
  @completed_set = current_user.completed_sets.build(params[:completed_set])
  ...
```

Comment: What is "user.update_workout_if_needed!" supposed to do? This method is where I'm most confused. If I can't get the user data, how do I know if the user workout needs to be updated?

Comment: Ohhhh. You can define a method in one model, and call it in another model?

Comment: `user` is an association defined in the `belongs_to :user` statement.  It loads the `user` based on the value of `user_id`.  You can then call methods on this user (assuming it can be found - that is, `user_id` is not `nil` and has a match in the database) as it is a standard User model.

Comment: I think that's the part that I was missing from all this! Since I can access the current user's ID from the User Model, I don't need to write all those instance methods in the controller, right?

Comment: `current_user` is only available in controllers/views.  You can access associated models directly from other models.  So `Workout.find(current_user.workout_id)` could be rewritten as `current_user.workout`, and `CompletedSet.where(:user_id => current_user.id)` as `current_user.completed_sets`.  Similarly, any model associated with the `current_user` can access it via `model.user`.  Of course, all this assumes you have your `belongs_to`, `has_many`, and `has_one` relationships set up...

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what the controller logic is supposed to do, so can't figure out how to get it to work. I updated my question with my new refactored model and controller code.

Comment: For one thing, read up on [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) - you are killing your database by calling `.find` explicitly instead of using associations.

Comment: A user doesn't have a direct association with a cycle, group, or workout, a user has a program, which has_many cycles. A cycles has_many groups, and a workout has_many exercises. A user is assigned a cycle, group, and workout based on the program they are assigned. Then the user progresses through the workouts in their program. Should I be tying the user directly to their cycle, group, and workout though an association even though those things are assigned based on the program the user has?

Comment: Absolutely, if there is a corresponding `model_id` you should have a `belongs_to` association except in rare circumstances.  As the `model_id` changes (or is nullified), the associated model changes to reflect that.